# Any way to define a System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo object based on PID of running process?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to define a new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo object for a running process. Is it possible? how?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: You can get the actual one from the running process like this:  `$startInfo = (Get-Process <ProcessName>).StartInfo`.  Why do you want to define a new one?  Sounds like a possible [X-Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)